# mapreduce slow Merging, How to speed up?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I submit a job with 9000+ mapper and 4096 reducer.
Each mapper's input is a hdfs file, about 10GB(50 million lines). 
Normally, one mapper run 25 minutes. 
However there are always about 1~10 mappers that run cost 1 hour.
These mappers' cleanup() happens 20 minutes after mapper's setup()
The Merging cost 40 minutes.
How to speed up the Merging?
Some logs:

```
2018-05-19 12:03:14,791 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Merging 8 sorted segments
2018-05-19 12:03:14,792 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 8 segments left of total size: 1282276 bytes
2018-05-19 12:03:14,805 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Merging 8 sorted segments
2018-05-19 12:03:14,810 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 8 segments left of total size: 1181792 bytes
2018-05-19 12:03:14,845 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Merging 8 sorted segments
2018-05-19 12:03:14,904 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 8 segments left of total size: 1028459 bytes
2018-05-19 12:03:14,912 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Merging 8 sorted segments
2018-05-19 12:03:14,913 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 8 segments left of total size: 988898 bytes
```

Comment: As currently phrased, you're not actually asking a question. What is the question you want us to answer? If it's why your code is slow, you might want to include the actual code.

Comment: mapper's merge is slow, how to speed up?

Comment: You really need to provide some code and example data to enable anyone to answer this.